# Seeking explanation of the advantages of async with/for

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-aiofiles

I'm new to asyncio. I came across AIOFiles (https://github.com/Tinche/aiofiles) recently and saw in the documentation that it supports 'async with' and 'async for.' I wanted to learn about it but there isn't much good coverage on it besides PEP 492 which doesn't go into too much detail.

Shortcuts to the relevant sections of PEP 492:

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#asynchronous-context-managers-and-async-with

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#asynchronous-iterators-and-async-for

I have a number of questions if somebody wouldn't mind answering:

1. The only discernible benefit of async iterators / context managers I am picking up on is that you can use awaitables in the implementations of their required magic methods. Am I missing something or is that it?
2. In PEP 492 regarding async context manager, it says "An asynchronous context manager is a context manager that is able to suspend execution in its enter and exit methods." Is this referring to calling coroutines using await?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The only discernible benefit of async iterators / context managers I am picking up on is that you can use awaitables in the implementations of their required magic methods. Am I missing something or is that it?

You're not missing anything, except perhaps the significance of the ability to suspend. Without suspendable magic methods, context managers and iterators would be useless for async work. For example, a regular file object serves as an iterator that produces the lines from the file. For an async file object (or a stream) to provide equivalent functionality, it must be able to await the line to come, and thereby suspend the coroutine that iterates over it. The same applies to a context manager whose entering must establish an async network connection, and so on.

> Is [being able to suspend execution] referring to calling coroutines using await?

Using `await` in an `async def` is one way to suspend execution. Another option is for `__aenter__` etc. to be normal functions that return a custom awaitable that implements its own `__await__`. PEP 492 describes the functionality from the vantage point of the code that uses the context manager, which must be ready for its magic methods to suspend -- `async with` must be inside an `async def` and it will desugar to code that `await`s in the appropriate places.

Comment: You wrote that  "For an async file object (or a stream) to provide equivalent functionality, it must be able to await the line to come." Judging by the "await the line to come" part, it seems to me that async file objects are to be used in situations where the contents of the file to be read are not present / will be added to the file at an uncertain point in the future; please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @D.Anderson That's a possible use case, but it's not necessary and is not what I was referring to. You might need async interface to regular file IO to support file reads from slow devices (spinning disks, network-mounted shares) without blocking the event loop. aiofiles which you mention in the question is exactly such a library: it exposes an async-capable interface toward ordinary file IO. Also, an async file object was just an example, you can also imagine an async interface to a socket (a stream), in which case you would definitely want to suspend while waiting for data to arrive.